# How to get previous node in foreach with dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have some html like the following

```
<tr>
<td colspan="3">hello</td>
</tr>
<tr class="RowName-Hide-YES" style="">
<td class="form-label-text">Page Tab: </td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">hello</td>
</tr>
<tr class="RowName-Hide-YES" style="">
<td class="form-label-text">Page Tab: </td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

What I need to select out all rows of RowName-Hide-YES and hide them along with the previous row.  Hiding the ones with the class is easy

```
dojo.query(".RowName-Hide-YES").style("display","none")
```

However to try and hide the row and the previous row I was trying to do:

```
dojo.query(".RowName-Hide-YES").forEach(function(node){node.style.display="none";node.prev().style.display="none"})
```

But it complains prev() doesn't exist.  Can anyone help me out with this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the reason the `prev()` doesn't work is because the `forEach()` callback passes a DOM node, not a `NodeList` (which is actually some kind of array with utility functions like `prev()` on it).

To make it work you have to wrap it inside a `dojo.query()` again, for example `dojo.query(node).prev()`. Another issue is that, because of the difference between a nodelist and a node, is that you can't directly apply `style.display` on it, but you'll have to either use the appropriate `NodeList` function, for example:

```
dojo.query(node).prev().style('display', 'none');
```

Or you have to retrieve the DOM node itself, for example:

```
dojo.query(node).prev()[0].style.display = 'none';
```

Also, please note that the `prev()` API is part of `dojo/NodeList-traverse` and the `style()` API is part of `dojo/NodeList-dom`. You have to include both modules to make it work.

A working example can be found on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/90o8fzpy/).

Comment: Thanks.  Now I know why it doesn't work.   Appreciate the thorough response.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out.  I need to do dojo.query again inside of the forEach to use prev

```
dojo.query(".RowName-Hide-YES").forEach(function(node){node.style.display="none";dojo.query(node).prev()[0].style.display="none";});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just hanging onto it yourself?

```
var previous = null;
dojo.query(".RowName-Hide-YES").forEach(function(node){
  node.style.display="none";
  if (previous) {
    previous.style.display="none";
  }
  previous = node;
});
```

Comment: I am not trying to hide the previous in the sense of the previous foreach.  I am trying to hide the row above it.    So like if I have row1,row2,row3,row4, my selector only grabs row 2 and 4 but I need to also hide the rows above them of 1 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you:

```
dojo.query(".RowName-Hide-YES").forEach(function(node){ node.closest('tr').style.display="none"; })
```

Comment: this just selects the RowName-Hide-YES row.  I need to hide the row before it.

Comment: Do you want to hide both the Rows of contains ".RowName-Hide-YES" class and the previous class. If this is your choice then you may traverse the table from a parent table and from that you have to find all the children that contain your desire class and then from here you also hide the prev() tr.

Or you want to hide all the rows??